# Exception occurs when using stanford nlp's SUTime package

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm trying to use Stanford NLP's SUTime through CoreNLP with this piece of code:

```
AnnotationPipeline pipeline = new AnnotationPipeline();
pipeline.addAnnotator(new TimeAnnotator("sutime", props));

Annotation annotation = new Annotation("The interesting date is 4 days from today and it is 20th july of this year, another date is 18th Feb 1997");
annotation.set(CoreAnnotations.DocDateAnnotation.class, "2013-07-14");
pipeline.annotate(annotation);
List<CoreMap> timexAnnsAll = annotation.get(TimeAnnotations.TimexAnnotations.class);
```

However, it turned out to throw this exception:

```
Reading TokensRegex rules from edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/defs.sutime.txt
Reading TokensRegex rules from edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/english.sutime.txt
Reading TokensRegex rules from edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/english.holidays.sutime.txt
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NumberNormalizer.findNumbers(NumberNormalizer.java:423)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NumberNormalizer.findAndMergeNumbers(NumberNormalizer.java:721)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorImpl.extractTimeExpressions(TimeExpressionExtractorImpl.java:184)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorImpl.extractTimeExpressions(TimeExpressionExtractorImpl.java:178)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorImpl.extractTimeExpressionCoreMaps(TimeExpressionExtractorImpl.java:116)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeAnnotator.annotateSingleSentence(TimeAnnotator.java:240)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeAnnotator.annotate(TimeAnnotator.java:226)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotationPipeline.annotate(AnnotationPipeline.java:68)
    at dd.stanford.main(stanford.java:74)
```

I'm using the version 3.5.2 from maven. Does any body know why's this exception? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is crashing because you didn't tokenize the text.

Change your code to:

```
AnnotationPipeline pipeline = new AnnotationPipeline();
pipeline.addAnnotator(new TokenizerAnnotator(false));
pipeline.addAnnotator(new TimeAnnotator("sutime", props));
```